# Postsharp compile error Ambiguous match System.Runtime.InteropServices

Tags: postsharp

I'm trying to add PostSharp Logging to a .NET Framework app.  I'm getting this error.  How do I resolve it?  Is there a way to tell PostSharp which type it should map to?

Unhandled exception (postsharp-x86-srv.exe 6.10.8 release | .NET Framework 4.8 (X86)): PostSharp.Sdk.CodeModel.BindingException:
Ambiguous match: need to map 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.ImportedFromTypeLibAttribute, System.Runtime.InteropServices, Culture=neutral, Context=Runtime' and have several candidates:
'System.Runtime.InteropServices.ImportedFromTypeLibAttribute, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, Context=Reference'
'System.Runtime.InteropServices.ImportedFromTypeLibAttribute, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, Context=Reference.

Comment: It should be enough to create a config file with a binding redirect to version 4.0.0.0 (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/redirect-assembly-versions). And then add the path to this file to the `@(PostSharpHostConfigurationFile)` item group in the project file. PostSharp should consume this config file and binding redirect.

Comment: It is not working for some reason.  I even tried the steps in this article from PostSharp with no luck.  I'm still getting the same error. https://doc.postsharp.net/assembly-binding-resolution#

Comment: Do you know which reference references assembly `mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0`? It would be a .NET 2/.NET 3.5 assembly that is being referenced (possibly indirectly) by your .NET 4+ project.

Comment: You can try using `/p:PostSharpTrace=AssemblyBinder` switch to get a more detailed overview of why PostSharp gets into the ambiguous match. Then, using `/v:d` switch will get you a detailed log file that should show you whether the config file was used by PostSharp. Config files are usually merged into `obj/$(Configuration)/PostSharp/postsharp.config` so you may check that file if it contains necessary binding redirects.

Comment: Using the trace I've found it is coming from a reference to LeadTools 16.5 and it is a .NET 3.5 assembly that references mscorlib 2.0.0.0.  Using the /v:d option I can see the log is loading my config file.  When I open the postsharp.merged.app.config I see my assembly binding in there.  I'm not sure why it isn't working.

Comment: Are you using any other tools that would be rewriting assemblies? If you inspect your references, is there any assembly that would be referencing both `mscorlib 2.0.0.0` and `mscorlib 4.0.0.0` at the same time? Since LeadTools 16.5 is not available I was not able to see what is happening in more detail.

Comment: This is an old VB.net app.  There are a lot of references but nothing else I can find that.  Should I post a list of project references?

Comment: Yes, also, which version of Visual Studio is it? If you could use a pastebin for the whole project file it would be useful.

Comment: Visual Studio 2019.  Here is the pastebin of the whole project file.  https://pastebin.com/CuwRk7Qz